# Hudson Continuous Integration. Copy contents of a folder to another folder (website)

Tags: asp.net, integration, hudson, continuous

Im trying out the Hudson Continuous Integration. After the build is executed i want to copy the content of the ReleaseBuild to another website on the server.

This should be possible i guess but i cant seem figure it out.

I know this can be done in nAnt and msbuild but i need to make Hudson do it, eg plugin or something.

Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hudson doesn't have a built in copy to some random location task so you have the following options

- Add another nant/msbuild step that does the deploy
- Install the [Post Build Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Post+build+task) and call a .cmd file to do your deploy
- Use the [Copy Archiver Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/CopyArchiver+Plugin) to do the copy  - more specific than the post build plugin. (Thanks @nos)

The extra task in your nant file is probably the best option as nant can control IIS and do the right thing rather than just copying the files into a folder.

Comment: Not entirely true, hudson has the CopyArchiver task, which lets you copy artifacts to any random filesystem destination.

Comment: @nos - My point referred to a built in process - Thanks for the suggestion of Copy Archiver - I've added it to the options - it's clearly better than the Post build plugin for this task but I still think a nant/msbuild task is the preferred way to go. Thoughts?

Comment: If you're only copying within the same server, there's no need for a plugin as it's so trivial. Otherwise there are plugins as mentioned, including the SCP Publisher plugin.

Comment: @nos - i have looked at CopyArchiver but i can only copy to a random dest, and since im want to deploy a website (asp.net) i need to set the location of the msbuild folder and this cant be done as far as i can see.
Am i wrong here?

Comment: @Christopher - Thats what i want. Could you explain what you mean?